# Starting activity doesn't bring application to foreground

Tags: android

I've got some strange problem with bringing the application to foreground. As it's said in Android documentation using startActivity(myIntent) should bring application from background and it worked until upgrade Android on HTC Desire HD to version 2.3.5. At this version this method doesn't work at all. Application is running in the background even if I add singleInstance flag

> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT.

This is the code snippet where I create the intent and launch activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(self.ctx, "com.app.WakeUp");
ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

The ctx variable is a context passed to the object from Activity instance and com.app.WakeUp is a name of Activity to start.

Some ideas what is going on?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are creating and launching the Intent?

Answer (score 0):

I almost forgot about this question.
The cause of the problem with waking up intent probably is a bug in HTC Desire HD with Android version 2.3.5 (unfortunatelly have no build number). Simple workaround (but not so simple to discover) is for example remote service which can bring the intent to the front.